# Error with the routing when I deploy my Angular 2 app

Tags: angular

I get this error:

```
Error: Not Found
at C:\Users\George\Desktop\EXPRESS SERVER LIVE\myapp\app.js:30:13
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\George\Desktop\EXPRESS SERVER LIVE\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\George\Desktop\EXPRESS SERVER LIVE\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at C:\Users\George\Desktop\EXPRESS SERVER LIVE\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\George\Desktop\EXPRESS SERVER LIVE\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\George\Desktop\EXPRESS SERVER LIVE\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at C:\Users\George\Desktop\EXPRESS SERVER LIVE\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
at next (C:\Users\George\Desktop\EXPRESS SERVER LIVE\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\George\Desktop\EXPRESS SERVER LIVE\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (C:\Users\George\Desktop\EXPRESS SERVER LIVE\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

I dont use routerLink="home" because I want a page to refresh every time I have a slider with images from materialize lib: http://materializecss.com/media.html,

if I use the `routerLink="home"` I will not refresh the page and I will not load the images, what I should do for that?

In the localhost 4200 everything works as expected, but not on my node.js server

When I run the express server is run the default page everything ok so far, but if I click on the links that I have on main navigation I get the error.

This is the `nav` component

```
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="arxiki">Αρχική</a></li>
    <li><a href="omilos">Όμιλος</a></li>
    <li><a href="kopilasia">Κοπηλασία</a></li>
    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
    <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

I am using an `href` attribute because the page must reload.

#### routing.module.ts

```
export const router: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'arxiki', pathMatch: 'full' }, // this will make your component the landing page
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'members', component: MembersComponent, canActivate : [AuthGuard] },

  { path: 'arxiki', component: ArxikiComponent },
  { path: 'omilos', component: OmilosComponent },
  { path: 'kopilasia', component: KopilasiaComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminLoginPageComponent },
  { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
]
```

Comment: In the nav component, I don't see router-outlet to display the content and also did you register the routing in app.modules.ts along with components .

Comment: Perhaps your server doesn't support HTML5 pushState. You could try `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true})]` and see if this fixes your issue (causes different browser URLs though). If it works this way, then you know you need to fix your server configuration to make it work with `PathLocationStrategy` (default).

Comment: i have router outlet in the angular cli all works ok if i take the dist folder that i have create from **ng build** and i paste that inside my express app publick folder the links dont work

Comment: thnx all of you for your help

Comment: i add this and is add localhost:3000/#/nome

Comment: can i  ask how i can refresh the home page when i click home. Is not load the images for my Slider what i  can do for taht ????